# How do I inject a CSP nonce into Angular's auto-generated script tags?

Tags: angular, webpack, content-security-policy, nonce

The [Angular docs mention CSP](https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy), and Google's Security Engineers [recommend against using whitelists](https://youtu.be/_L06HetskC4?t=674). What I haven't figured out yet is how to inject a nonce into the script tag(s) that Angular injects into the index.html (to "bootstrap" itself). I suppose it has to do with Webpack, but the `ng eject` command has been removed from the cli a while ago, I believe, and I haven't been able to find a tutorial on this. Can anyone get me started with pointers, please?

The [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/csp/) mention that a variable

```
__webpack_nonce__ = 'let-nonce-string-be-injected-by-server-here';
```

needs to be defied in the entry file (not the config - so an [@angular-builders/custom-webpack npm module](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders) is probably not going to help?), but I'm not clear what Webpack's entry file is in the context of Angular...?

P.S.: Judging from [this blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-angular-7-a-complete-guide-9a23c879f471/), the polyfill file is one of the entry files - but it looks like it's not the first, so I doubt adding the variable there will work...?

Comment: NB: One can use `ng build --subresourceIntegrity=true` to enable [SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) and use [hashes in CSP](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash) instead.

Comment: Random: Using `strict-dynamic` ignores whitelists (other than hashes) in a CSP directive. However, [adding several headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Multiple_content_security_policies) (or separating the same directive type by comma; [slide 45](https://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2019ams/materials/D1T1%20-%20CSP%20-%20A%20Successful%20Mess%20Between%20Hardening%20and%20Mitigation%20-%20Lukas%20Weichselbaum%20&%20Michele%20Spagnuolo.pdf)) is apparently additive.

Comment: Hashes instead of nonces only work since CSP 3 with external scripts, though. (And if you want to use a new patch version of an external JS, nonces continue to work, while you'd have to add a new hash.) On the other hand, hashes can be cached; nonces not so much.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @MrN1ceGuy I haven't looked into this in a while (got moved to a different project), but here are the two issue tickets that might give you some hints: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37631 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6361